# Text files being downloaded from zipped files, accessed via urls, being downloaded to working directory and not to global environment in R

Tags: r, url, download, sapply

I am trying to retrieve multiple data txt files, that match a certain pattern, form multiple zipped files that I access through urls. I wrote a script that downloads the desired dataframe files from the url, saving them in a list, then rbinds all the dataframes together. I then sapply the function over a list of urls.

My desired end result is to have all the downloaded data form all urls in a single dataframe in the global environment in R.

Currently however, the individual files get downloaded into my working directory, which I don't want, and are not combined into a single dataframe. I'm wondering whether this problem stems from `download.file`, but I have been unable to find a solution or posts with similar issues.

```
# list of urls
url_df = data.frame(model = c("rcp26", "rcp45", "rcp85"),  
                    url = c("https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/files/d4850267-3ce2-44f4-b5e3-8391a4f3dc27/LTER_site_data_from_EURO-CORDEX-RCMs_rel1.see_disclaimer.77c127c4-2ebe-453b-b5af-61858ff02e31.huss_historical_rcp26_day_txt.zip",
"https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/files/d4850267-3ce2-44f4-b5e3-8391a4f3dc27/LTER_site_data_from_EURO-CORDEX-RCMs_rel1.see_disclaimer.77c127c4-2ebe-453b-b5af-61858ff02e31.huss_historical_rcp45_day_txt.zip",
"https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/files/d4850267-3ce2-44f4-b5e3-8391a4f3dc27/LTER_site_data_from_EURO-CORDEX-RCMs_rel1.see_disclaimer.77c127c4-2ebe-453b-b5af-61858ff02e31.huss_historical_rcp85_day_txt.zip"))

# create empty dataframe where data will be saved
downloaded_data = data.frame()

# create function to retrieve desired files from a single url
get_data = function(url) {
  temp <- tempfile() # create temp file
  download.file(url,temp) # download file contained in the url
  
  # get a list of the desired files
  file.list <- grep("KNMI-RACMO22E.*txt|MPI-CSC-REMO.*txt|SMHI-RCA4.*txt", unzip(temp, list=TRUE)$Name, ignore.case=TRUE, value=TRUE)
  
  data.list = lapply(unzip(temp, files=file.list), read.table, header=FALSE,  comment.char = "", check.names = FALSE)
  
  # bind the dataframes in the list into one single dataframe
  bound_data = dplyr::bind_rows(data.list)
  
  downloaded_data = rbind(downloaded_data, bound_data )
  
  return(downloaded_data)
  
  unlink(temp)
}

# apply function over the list of urls
sapply(url_df$url, get_data)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to `downloaded_data` within the function -- the function will be applied to each URL separately, and then you can bind them together to create `downloaded_data`. There were also some changes to the unzipping and reading in of the data to make sure the files were actually being read in.

```r
# list of urls
url_df = data.frame(model = c("rcp26", "rcp45", "rcp85"),  
                    url = c("https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/files/d4850267-3ce2-44f4-b5e3-8391a4f3dc27/LTER_site_data_from_EURO-CORDEX-RCMs_rel1.see_disclaimer.77c127c4-2ebe-453b-b5af-61858ff02e31.huss_historical_rcp26_day_txt.zip",
                            "https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/files/d4850267-3ce2-44f4-b5e3-8391a4f3dc27/LTER_site_data_from_EURO-CORDEX-RCMs_rel1.see_disclaimer.77c127c4-2ebe-453b-b5af-61858ff02e31.huss_historical_rcp45_day_txt.zip",
                            "https://b2share.eudat.eu/api/files/d4850267-3ce2-44f4-b5e3-8391a4f3dc27/LTER_site_data_from_EURO-CORDEX-RCMs_rel1.see_disclaimer.77c127c4-2ebe-453b-b5af-61858ff02e31.huss_historical_rcp85_day_txt.zip"))

# create function to retrieve desired files from a single url
get_data = function(url) {
  temp <- tempdir() # create temp file
  download.file(url, file.path(temp, "downloaded.zip")) # download file contained in the url
  downloaded_files <- unzip(file.path(temp, "downloaded.zip"), exdir = temp)
  keep_files <- downloaded_files[grep("KNMI-RACMO22E.*txt|MPI-CSC-REMO.*txt|SMHI-RCA4.*txt", 
                                      downloaded_files)]
  data.list <- lapply(keep_files, read.table, header=FALSE,  comment.char = "", check.names = FALSE)
  # bind the dataframes in the list into one single dataframe
  bound_data = dplyr::bind_rows(data.list)
  return(bound_data)
  unlink(temp)
}

# apply function over the list of urls
downloaded_data <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(url_df$url, get_data))
dim(downloaded_data)
#> [1] 912962      7
```

Comment: This helped for getting a combined document in the global environment, but the documents still get downloaded into my working directory when I have one set. Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's actually happening in the `unzip` step. I'll add `exdir = temp` to my answer, which will keep them in that temporary directory

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you for your help